# How to write a long square root?

Tags: equations

I am having such a hard time to write this formula in the LaTeX form. I have never used LaTeX before and I know this is not difficult, but how to get that long square root and exponential? Any help will be appreciated. Thanks.

[image]

Comment: Is there a problem with `\sqrt{}` ?

Comment: What you've done so far? I believe any tutorial about latex for beginners definitely addresses this issue. By the way, there is no difference between having a long or short expression inside the `\sqrt{}`. It expands as you wish.

Comment: I'm pretty sure you should ask a new question rather than completely overhaul this one. Assuming this is even a question worth asking...

Comment: If you have a second question, please ask it as a second question. Rewriting your previous question makes good answers look out of place.

Comment: Please post a new question and revert this one back to the original question so that the answer below has is relevant and could help someone else in the future who has the same problem as you.  Only edit questions to clarify things, not to ask a new question.

Comment: I rolled back to the original question, or the answers would be invalid. Please, don't change questions this way. If you have a new question, ask a different one.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

This is the answer to your question.

```
\documentclass{article}

\begin{document}
\[
\mathit{dist} = 
\sqrt{ \left( \frac{dx}{hx} \right)^{\!\!2} +  \left( \frac{dy}{hy} \right)^{\!\!2} +  \left( \frac{dz}{hz} \right)^{\!\!2}}
\]
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: I would hesitate to call it 'the' answer, especially as `dist` should be set as text with `\text{}` (if loading `amsmath`) or `\mbox{}`, or - at least - using `\mathit{}` so it is treated as a unit and not as the product of four variables, giving the correct spacing between, especially, `i` and `s`

Comment: @Au101, you are correct. I've updated 'the' answer. But still an answer though. :)

Comment: And now a very good one :) I personally agree that it is best to set fractions under the radical in in-line style, rather than display style

Comment: @Sally7874, you are welcome.

Comment: A good refinement would be typing in the exponents as `^{\!\! 2}`, in order to compensate for the large parenthesis. At least one `\!` is needed anyway.

Comment: @egreg, I've updated the answer. Thank you for your feedback.

Answer (score 3):

It is actually pretty easy ... if you do not see any problem with this of course.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}

\begin{document}

\begin{equation}
\mathit{dist} = \sqrt{\left(\dfrac{dx}{hx}\right)^2 + \left(\dfrac{dy}{hy}\right)^2 + \left(\dfrac{dz}{hz}\right)^2}
\end{equation}

\end{document}
```

[image]

In summary :

- `\sqrt` for the square root
- `\left(` and `\right)` to enclose the fractions inside brackets matching the height of the `\dfrac` fraction inside.

Comment: Since the material is in displaystyle math mode, `\dfrac` and `\frac` produce the same output.

Comment: apologies for overhauling and thank you all for your answers!:)